# Android Kotlin - EditText TextWatcher not working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I am working on a Fragment that has two Edit text. The first one takes card 16 digits and the second one expiry. First one is working and the second one is not. When I input numbers in the first edit text, I can see the logs in logcat but for the second one, there are no logs in logcat.
That makes me think the listener is not working.

My XML file snippet

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/text_field_card_number"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/field_rounded_white"
        android:hint="@string/screen_text_card_number"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/NormalText.TransactionInstruction.AllCaps"
        android:textColor="@color/colorTextGrey"
        android:focusedByDefault="true"
        android:maxLength="19"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.13"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image_back_top"/>

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/text_field_expiry"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/field_rounded_black"
        android:hint="@string/screen_text_expiry"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/NormalText.TransactionInstruction.AllCaps"
        android:textColor="@color/colorTextGrey"
        android:maxLength="5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.13"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_field_card_number"/>
```

Kotlin code is as below

```
cardNumber = findViewById(R.id.text_field_card_number)
cardExpiry = findViewById(R.id.text_field_expiry) 
cardExpiry.addTextChangedListener(cardExpiryTextWatcher)
cardNumber.addTextChangedListener(cardNumberTextWatcher)
    
    
    
        private var cardNumberTextWatcher = object : TextWatcher {
    
            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            }
    
            override fun beforeTextChanged(
                s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int,
                after: Int
            ) {
            }
    
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
                val inputLength: Int = cardNumber.text.length
                Log.e("afterTextChanged", "$s + count: $cardNumberCount + input length: $inputLength")
    
                if (inputLength == CARD_NUMBER_FIELD_MAX_LENGTH) {
                    cardNumberRedCross.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    cardNumber.isClickable = true
    
                } else {
                    cardNumberRedCross.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    cardNumber.isClickable = false
                }
    
                if (cardNumberCount <= inputLength && (inputLength == 4 ||
                            inputLength == 9 || inputLength == 14)
                ) {
                    cardNumber.setText(cardNumber.text.toString() + " ")
    
                    val pos: Int = cardNumber.length()
                    cardNumber.setSelection(pos)
    
                } else if (cardNumberCount >= inputLength && (inputLength == 4 ||
                            inputLength == 9 || inputLength == 14)
                ) {
                    /* Remove space when deleting number */
                    Log.e("TAG", " count> input")
                    cardNumber.setText(
                        cardNumber.text.toString()
                            .substring(0, cardNumber.length() - 1)
                    )
    
                    var pos: Int = cardNumber.length()
                    cardNumber.setSelection(pos)
                }
                cardNumberCount = cardNumber.length()
            }
        }
    
        private var cardExpiryTextWatcher = object : TextWatcher {
    
            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            }
    
            override fun beforeTextChanged(
                s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int,
                after: Int
            ) {
            }
    
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
                val inputLength: Int = cardExpiry.text.length
                Log.e(
                    "cardExpiryTextWatcher",
                    "$s + count: $cardExpiryCount + input length: $inputLength"
                )
    
                if (inputLength == CARD_EXPIRY_FIELD_MAX_LENGTH) {
                    expiryRedCross.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    expiryRedCross.isClickable = true
                    cardExpiry.isFocusable = true
                    cardExpiry.isFocusableInTouchMode = true
                    cardExpiry.requestFocus()
    
                } else {
                    expiryRedCross.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    expiryRedCross.isClickable = false
                }
    
                if (cardExpiryCount <= inputLength && (inputLength == 5)) {
                    cardExpiry.setText(cardExpiry.text.toString() + "/")
    
                    val pos: Int = cardExpiry.length()
                    cardExpiry.setSelection(pos)
    
                } else if (cardExpiryCount >= inputLength && (inputLength == 5)) {
                    /* Remove space when deleting number */
                    Log.e("TAG", " count> input")
                    cardExpiry.setText(
                        cardExpiry.text.toString()
                            .substring(0, cardExpiry.length() - 1)
                    )
    
                    var pos: Int = cardExpiry.length()
                    cardExpiry.setSelection(pos)
                }
                cardExpiryCount = cardExpiry.length()
            }
        }
```

Am I missing anything here, does anyone have any example with 2 text watchers?
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: At first glance it looks like you should be seeing output. You're not filtering logcat in a way that would prevent you from seeing the other logs are you?

Comment: No, I am not adding any kind of filtering.